# cross domain file upload in blueimp

Tags: file-upload, cross-domain, blueimp

I am using blueimp plugin to upload a file. It's working on local server but when I try to use a different domain file it doesn't save over there. Please help me with what I have to do. I have written the following code

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        url: 'http://192.168.1.205/EncoderService/API/Default.aspx'
    });

    // Enable iframe cross-domain access via redirect option:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload(
        'option',
        'redirect',
        window.location.href.replace(
            /\/[^\/]*$/,
            '/cors/result.html?%s'
        )
    );
```

Is there any need to write code in the server side or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I set WithCrentials: false 
Its works for me.